# Use device mic during call

Tags: java, android, tokbox

My app makes video / audio call (via TokBox), i need to use SpeechToText service (SpeechRecognizer) during the call.

From what I read, i can not use the device mic (stream) for two uses in the same time.

I tried to disable the call for a moment or mute the audio to fire the SpeechToText, but it is work only when i hang-up the call (Unpublished / Disconnect)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the custom audio driver https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-samples/tree/master/Custom-Audio-Driver to access the audio samples